# java create date object using a value string

Tags: java, date

I am using this to get the current time :

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss")
            .format(cal.getTime()));
```

I want to put the value (which I print it) into a date object, I tried this:

```
Date currentDate = new Date(value);
```

but eclipse tells me that this function is not good.

**Edit**
the `value` is the value that I printed to you using system.out.println

Comment: Dinatsoil What is value. Please specify clearly.

Comment: What are you using for `value`?

Comment: `value` is a `String`? You also have to parse it with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: `hh` is twelve hour format, `HH` twenty four hour format. Without AM/PM probably **HH**.

Comment: Your program is also running on MyEclipse without any problem.Then what you really need.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `Date` & `Calendar` classes are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Whenever you want to convert a String to Date object then use `SimpleDateFormat#parse`
Try to use

```
String dateInString = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss")
        .format(cal.getTime())
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

.Additional thing is if you want to convert a `Date` to `String` then you should use `SimpleDateFormat#format` function.
Now the Point for you is 
 `new Date(String)` is deprecated and not recommended now.Now whenever anyone wants to parse , then he/she should use `SimpleDateFormat#parse`.

refer the [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more Date and Time Patterns used in SimpleDateFormat options.

Comment: It is your date in String format.You need to set format in in `new SimpleDateFormat(format)` exactly as your string have and then just need to parse it.As your `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss")
             .format(cald.getTime())` will return a String and in question I guess you want to convert it into `Date` then this is the way that I answered

Comment: what is dateInString?? i didn't parse anything,

Comment: +1 `dateInString` is the string you have which you want to turn into a date.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli please see the updated answer.I hope now you would understand what is `dateInString`

Comment: the resutls for ur code is `Thu Apr 25 00:23:26 PDT 2013` and it is not in the format which i want , why please?

Comment: because now you are printing `java.util.Date` and you cannot override its format by using `java.util.Date`.If you want to print your desired format then you have to `format` your date otherwise with using `Date` object , you can't do this.Simply you can say that The Date class does not store any information about formatting. The Date class exist basically merely of a private long milliseconds field

Answer (score 36):

Use SimpleDateFormat parse method:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

String inputString = "11-11-2012";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(inputString, dateFormat );
```

Since we have Java 8 with LocalDate I would suggest use next:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String inputString = "11-11-2012";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(inputString,formatter);
```

Comment: @bharal the java.util.Date is legacy from older java. Now it is time to use LocalDate

Comment: Last line is missing the fromatter: It could be a follows
LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(inputString, formatter);

Answer (score 3):

**FIRST OF ALL KNOW THE REASON WHY ECLIPSE IS DOING SO.**

Date has only one constructor **Date(long date)** which asks for date in long data type.

The constructor you are using

**Date(String s)**
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).

Thats why eclipse tells that this function is not good.

See this official docs

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html**

---

**Deprecated methods from your context -- Source -- http://www.coderanch.com/t/378728/java/java/Deprecated-methods**

There are a number of reasons why a method or class may become deprecated. An API may not be easily extensible without breaking backwards compatibility, and thus be superseded by a more powerful API (e.g., java.util.Date has been deprecated in favor of Calendar, or the Java 1.0 event model). It may also simply not work or produce incorrect results under certain circumstances (e.g., some of the java.io stream classes do not work properly with some encodings). Sometimes an API is just ill-conceived (SingleThreadModel in the servlet API), and gets replaced by nothing. And some of the early calls have been replaced by "Java Bean"-compatible methods (size by getSize, bounds by getBounds etc.)

---

**SEVRAL SOLUTIONS ARE THERE JUST GOOGLE IT--**

You can use date(long date) By converting your date String into long milliseconds and stackoverflow has so many post for that purpose.

**[converting a date string into milliseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427169/converting-a-date-string-into-milliseconds-in-java)**

Answer (score 3):

```
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Above is the import method, below is the simple code for Date

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();

 system.out.println((dateFormat.format(date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
try{
        String valuee="25/04/2013";
        Date currentDate =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(valuee);
        System.out.println("Date is ::"+currentDate);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error::"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:-

```
   Date is ::Thu Apr 25 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013
```

Your value should be proper format.

In your question also you have asked for this below  :-

```
   Date currentDate = new Date(value);
```

This style of date constructor is already deprecated.So, its no more use.Being we know that Date has 6 constructor.[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the optimized solution to do it with `SimpleDateFormat` `parse()` method.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss");
String strDate = formatter.format(new Date());

try {
    Date pDate = formatter.parse(strDate);
} catch (ParseException e) { // note: parse method can throw ParseException
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Few things to notice

- We don't need to create a Calendar instance to get the current date
  & time instead use `new Date()`
- Also it **doesn't require 2 instances** of    `SimpleDateFormat` as
  found in the most voted answer for this    question. It's just a
  **waste of memory**
- Furthermore, catching a generic exception like `Exception` is a bad practice when we know that the `parse` method only stands a chance to throw a `ParseException`. We need to **be as specific as possible** when dealing with Exceptions. You can refer, [throws Exception bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966148/throws-exception-bad-practice/7966171#7966171)

Answer (score 1):

try this, it worked for me.

```
 String inputString = "01-01-1900";
    Date inputDate= null;
    try {
        inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(inputString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(inputDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because value coming String ([Java Date object constructor for getting string is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823797/java-date-object-constructor-for-getting-string-is-deprecated))

and `Date(String)` is deprecated.

Have a look at [jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or  you could put @SuppressWarnings({“deprecation”}) outside the method calling the `Date(String)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically trying to do is this:-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

The reason being, the `String` which you're printing is just a `String` representation of the `Date` in your required format. If you try to convert it to date, you'll eventually end up doing what I've mentioned above.

Formatting `Date`(**cal.getTime()**) to a `String` and trying to get back a `Date` from it - makes no sense. `Date` has no format as such. You can only get a `String` representation of that using the SDF.