# How to parse specific format of date string

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have these strings

```
String day1 = "June 3, 2015";
```

and

```
String day2 = "June 25, 2015";
```

I want create a method to parse out the month, day and year. Currently I am using substring() but think there may be a better solution?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208121/java-create-date-object-using-a-value-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and parse the date from there.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
Date date1 = format.parse(day1);
Date date2 = format.parse(day2);
```

Comment: ROLF, this is the same approach I follow just now :D

Answer (score 0):

Note this is equivalent to `MMMM dd, yyyy`

Try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
Date parsed = sdf.parse(day1, new ParsePosition(0));
...
```

Ps: I am not tried this code, please, feel free to comment anything.

Reference [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1 :

Use StringTokenizer to tokenize the string For example :

```
String str = "June 3, 2015";
StringTokenizer defaultTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (defaultTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    System.out.println(defaultTokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Remove ',' from date i.e 2nd token using deletecharAt(int index);

Hope that works for you

Solution 2 :
Using split() method

```
for (String retval: Str.split(" ", 3)){
         System.out.println(retval);
}

split() takes two argument first it will take the token , and the limit is how many strings. still you have to remove ',' .
```

There is another easiest solution :
Solution 3 :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
Date date1 = format.parse(day1);
Date date2 = format.parse(day2);
```

Comment: The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says: *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.*

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like

```
private static final String DAY = "dd";
private static final String MONTH = "MM";
private static final String YEAR = "yyyy";//use the format you want this just an example
Format month = new SimpleDateFormat(MONTH);
Format day = new SimpleDateFormat(DAY);
Format year = new SimpleDateFormat(YEAR);
month.format(your date); 
day.format(your date); 
year.format(your date);
```