# How to get Firestore document collection where date range

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a field name called `PurchaseDate` in every document of Cloud Firestore. Now I want to get all documents where the year in PurchaseDate is 2019.

In Firestore date timestamp is store as below screenshot

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also show us where you got stuck.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have edited my question, please check once.

Comment: This is your schema, good, but what have you tried in code?

Comment: String queryDate = "16-01-2019";

        database.collection("Abcdt/currenUser/EFC")
                .whereEqualTo("PurchaseDate", queryDate)
                .get()

Comment: You'll need to convert the string to an actual Java `Date` object. For an example of that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208121/java-create-date-object-using-a-value-string

Comment: I think the best approach is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502494/2860701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the following lines of code:

```
String queryDate = "16-01-2019"; 
database.collection("Abcdt/currenUser/EFC").whereEqualTo("PurchaseDate", queryDate).get();
```

It means that you are trying to query the database using a literal String, which is not correct since in your database your `PurchaseDate` property is of type `Date`. So to solve this, instead of passing as a the second argument a String, pass a `Date` object.

Comment: can you please share the Date object how to pass the same

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object) is how you can convert your `queryDate` String to a Date object. Does it work now?

Comment: request to kindly suggest the complete code to convert the same

Comment: Stack Overflow isn **not** a code writing service. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Hi Alex, still my issue not resolved. For temporarily I have completed the task with other option. Otherwise, can you please suggest to get the result with Year only.

Comment: Hi Sabir, I think this approach is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502494/2860701