# FireStore date query not working as expected

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have doc which has a date object.

Code to init Firestore:

```
 FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
        fireStore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
        firestore = fireStore;
```

Code to query:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FireStoreUtils.getInstance();
Query query= db.collection(viewType.collectionName());
        query.whereLessThan("endDate", new Date()); 
        return query.orderBy(viewType.sortProperty()).limit(PAGE_SIZE);
```

I am always getting all the records and looks like the where clause is not getting applied. On Firebase console I see that the `endDate` is stored as timestamp.

Doc from Firebase console:

```
createdDate: null (null)
description: "desc" (string)
endDate: February 3, 2019 at 11:18:58 PM UTC-8 (timestamp)
id: "-7475596197450085332" (string)
title: "title"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Firestore queries are immutable, which means that you cannot change the properties of an existing query. If you change the value by calling `whereLessThan()` method, it becomes a new query. So to solve this, please chain all method calls and store them in a new `Query` object like this:

```
Query query = db.collection(viewType.collectionName())
    .whereLessThan("endDate", new Date())
    .orderBy(viewType.sortProperty()).limit(PAGE_SIZE);
return query;
```

Comment: The semicolon after the ```.whereLessThan()``` argument should be removed. If it's left there the query would finalize there and the ```.orderBy()``` will give you an error.

Comment: @JaimeMirandaRamirez Yes, that's correct. I just updated my answer. Thank you, Jaime.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and my solution comparing and filtering dates is this:

Note that firebase store `Date` as `Timestamp` so instead of create a `Date` to compare, I create a `Timestamp` instead.

Remember to import `Timestamp` from Firebase:

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
```

Code to query:

```
val currentDate = Timestamp.now() // Firebase Date as Timestamp

FirebaseFirestore db = FireStoreUtils.getInstance();
Query query= db.collection(viewType.collectionName());
        query.whereLessThan("endDate", currentDate.toDate()); 

return query.orderBy(viewType.sortProperty()).limit(PAGE_SIZE);
```

I'm using firebase version:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.3.1"
```

I hope it helps!!