# Can you chain multiple whereEqualTo operations in one query in pieces in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have a multiple-choice dialog with various filter options that the user should be able to choose in order to filter the database based on the `rarity` field of the documents. Since there are many options in the filter dialog, covering each case by hand would take ages if we take into account all the possible combinations of the filters. With that in mind, I tried creating a starting query as you can see below and then I iterate through the list of filters selected by the user and try to add a `whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)` operation to the query for each filter. I noticed that you can't concatenate queries like with normal variables e.g. `var i += 5` so i would like to know if there is any solution to this kind of issue. **Can you actually apply multiple** `whereEqualTo` **operations in the** **same query in steps/pieces** **without overriding the previously applied operations on that same query**?

Here's what I've tried after receiving the filters selected by the user in my FilterActivity.kt class:

```
class FilterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter)

        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val filters:ArrayList<String>? = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("filterOptions")
        Log.d("FilterActivity", "filter options $filters")

        var query = db.collection("Cards").orderBy("resID")

        for(filter in filters!!) {
            query = query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)
        }

        query.get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
            if(querySnapshot.isEmpty) Log.d("FilterActivity","is empty")
            for(doc in querySnapshot.documents) {
                Log.d("FilterActivity", "${doc.getString("name")} - ${doc.getString("rarity")}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You chain as may whereEqualTo operations as you need. But what's wrong with this code?

Comment: I get errors from the IDE before compilation when i try to use the += operators on the query object but i can't see the error popup window because it's blinking too fast and non stoo for some reason

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo the issue is that the app won't even run due to the += operator on the query. I'm updating my post with the log from Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are trying a do **OR** operation, where you are retrieving all documents, in which rarity fields matched any of the value in array.

You are try new firebase [**whereIn**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) operation where you can pass array of values, but theres a limitation of max **10** values in filter

```
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Cards")
            .orderBy("resID")
            .whereIn("rarity",filters!!.toList())
            .get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                if (querySnapshot.isEmpty) Log.d("FilterActivity", "is empty")
                for (doc in querySnapshot.documents) {
                    Log.d("FilterActivity", "${doc.getString("name")} - ${doc.getString("rarity")}")
                }
            }
```

filters arraylist can contain max 10 values

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

> Can you chain multiple whereEqualTo operations in one query in pieces in Firestore

You can chain as may whereEqualTo operations as you need.

The problem in your code `+=` operator. There is no way you can make an addition/concatenation of two Query objects. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
query += query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)
```

to

```
query = query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)
```

Comment: Will each run of the if block in my code overwrite the previous whereEqualTo operation or does it get implicitly concatenated?

Comment: It adds another call to `whereEqualTo`. Give it a try.

Comment: This was one of the first things i tried when i came across the += issue but when i tried doing `query = query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)` the results from the query.get() are always empty. I tried it again just in case but still no results. Shouldn't this code return all the documents that have a "rarity" value of either "R" or "N" if i were to select the R & N filters?

Comment: If you select "R" or "N", you'll have either a filter with "R" or "N". If you want both filters, then you should add both `whereEqualTo` calls. But remember, [Firestore queries are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511674/firestore-date-query-not-working-as-expected/54512473#54512473).

Comment: Yeah i'd like to be able to apply all the user selected filters at once so in this case both R & N. Since the queries are immutable and i can't concatenate them, in order to cover all the possible combinations of filters, is the only solution to write them by hand in a huge if statement for example?

Comment: Just create a global query and add `whereEqualTo` calls according to the filters that are selected. In the end, you should have a query that has two `whereEqualTo` calls, right? I don't think there is a concrete example. You should write your own code.

Comment: Sorry i'm having some trouble understanding the logic here. Let's say i did the following :  var query = db.collection("Cards").orderBy("resID")

        for(filter in filters!!) {
            query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)
        } and the filters arraylist had "R" & "N" in it. The for-each loop will run twice but does that count as doing `query.whereEqualTo("rarity","R").whereEqualTo("rarity","N")` ?

Comment: As long as you are using inside the look `query = query.whereEqualTo("rarity",filter)`, it will works as `query.whereEqualTo("rarity","R").whereEqualTo("rarity","N")`. Every new `whereEqualTo` call should be saved in a new Query object. Does it work now?

Comment: I've done that but it still returns an empty query snapshot. I've updated my code on the post too if you're interested. I know for a fact that in my database i have variorus documents that have a rarity value of "R" and other various documents with a rarity value of "N" but instead of returning all of these, it returns an empty query snapshot.

Comment: It's empty because you didn't create a [Firestore index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working). If you create it, does it work now?

Comment: I have the following composite indexes in firebase : resID Ascending rarity Ascending and vice verca

Comment: You need to have also an index for the combined `whereEqualTo` calls. If you create that combined index, does it work?

Comment: How do i create such an index? The composite index only allows different fields.

Comment: In that case, you should remove the call to orderBy and then no index is needed anymore. That's a request that should be sent to the Firebase team.

Comment: If i remove the orderBy call then the query variable turns into a CollectionReference one. There's bound to be a solution for this out there, i'll probably add a bounty later on and hope someone has faced this before and knows of a workaround :) . Thank you very much for taking so much time to help me out