# Android firestore changing the way data is loaded

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a dating app.

I want the search method to be applied instead of the existing search method when the user sets the region and personality.

Here is a search code.

```
private void EventChangeListener() {
   
    firestore.collection("Users")
            //.whereEqualTo("mbti","ENTP")
            //.whereEqualTo("region","korea")
            .whereEqualTo("gender","male")
            .orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Log.e("Firestore error",error.getMessage());
                        return;

                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                            userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class));
                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

If the user selects a region and personality,
how about calling a new function(including "mbti","region") again?

EventChangeListener() and EventChangeListener()' (including mbti, region)
->> Are both functions executed again when data is updated?

Please let me know if there is any other good way.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors, but I am curious about the overall direction.

Comment: @AlexMamo I will implement my code.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have a problem when I call EventChangeListener() and transformed EventChangeListener() (has region, mbti) -> Users data appear duplicated below (when folllowing the scroll). So I want to initialize recyclerview, do you know a method please?

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebase-UI library?

Comment: @AlexMamo Do you mean this? -> https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Yes, that library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
val collection = firestore.collection("Users")
if(personalitySet) {
    collection.whereEqualTo("mbti","ENTP")
}
if(regionSet) {
    collection.whereEqualTo("region","korea")
}
collection.whereEqualTo("gender","male")
.orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
     ... etc
```

`personalitySet` and `regionSet` are two new `Boolean` variables you will have to create.

Comment: Hey Blundell. Please note that [Cloud Firestore queries are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511674/firestore-date-query-not-working-as-expected/54512473#54512473).