# can't java unchecked exceptions be handled using try/catch block?

Tags: java, exception

In a tutorial I found **that Unchecked Exception can't be handled by your code** i.e. we can't use `try/catch` block and the examples are exceptions like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, NullPointerException.` But these exceptions can be handled using try/catch block. I think i am not clear about the concept !!

Also i think throw keyword can be used only with `try/catch` block.can throw Keyword be used with `UncheckedException`?

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial?

Comment: and then there are `Error`s which are like unchecked exceptions, except that they are not `Exception`s and you are not supposed to catch them at all (but you could anyway).

Comment: You can even throw `Throwable` and its sub-classes (which are neither Error nor Exception)  These are treated as like checked exceptions by the compiler.  These are all caught by `catch(Throwable t)`

Comment: Tutorial is wrong. Where did you read that? Or else it doesn't say that, it just says that the compiler won't enforce catch or throws of RuntimeExceptions and Errors.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The only difference between checked and unchecked exceptions is that checked ones *have* to be either caught or declared in the method signature using `throws`, whereas with unchecked ones this is optional.

> Unchecked Exception can't be handled by your code i.e. we can't use try/catch block

Sure we can - but we don't have to.

> Also i think throw keyword can be used only with try/catch block.can throw Keyword be used with Unchecked Exception?

Note that there are *two* keywords:

- `throw` explicitly throws an exception object you created. `throw new NullPointerException();` works perfectly fine, though explicitly creating that particular exception is uncommon and most would consider it bad style.
- `throws` declares that a method may throw that exception. With unchecked exceptions this is optional, but can be useful to document the fact (again, one would normally not declared `throws NullPointerException` because that is pretty much a given).

Comment: Why do you say that throwing new instances of exceptions is uncommon/bad style? In any case, someone *needs* to create the exception isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier I was talking specifically about NullPointerException, which is normally created by the JRE, not by Java code.

Comment: If our function requires a non-null input but the calling code sends in a null input, would it not be appropriate to throw a new `NullPointerException` (optionally wrapped within an "illegal argument" exception e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`)? The alternative seems to be using our variables *as if* they are not null and letting the JRE throw a `NullPointerException` halfway throughout our function, but that seems clunky and not robust to unexpected errors.

Comment: @Pacerier: A plain IllegalArgumentException would be the right choice

Comment: "Sure we can - but we don't have to." What about logging?

Comment: @PieterDeBie: what about it?

Comment: Catch the RuntimeException, log something, throw it further.

Comment: @Pieter De Bie: if you feel that there's information that needs to be logged, sure. But it's not something you have to do. Usually the exception itseld (and its stack trace) should contain enough information to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt If you had spent any time in system administration you would have expected the developer to have catch, logged and provided any further state information in the logs before allowing the code to blow up. Not doing so unfortunately is very common (lack of developer education) and very expensive on a production system.

Comment: @Salvador: Sure, if there actually is useful state information (in which case it's still a better option to add it to the exception instead of logging *and* rethrowing). Careless logging leads to bloated logs which make diagnosis harder, not easier - especially when they get turned off entirely because the system spends 50% of its time writing logs and the HD is constantly overflowing.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Yes correct, any useful data for critical transaction rollbacks would be essential. No irrevelant status comments that just pad logs.

Answer (score 11):

All the unchecked exceptions can be treated in the same way as the checked ones - if you want, you can let them pass by declaring that the method `throws` them:

```
public void m() throws RuntimeException {}
```

Or you can `catch` them:

```
public void m() {
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It should be noticed, the class `RuntimeException` acts as a catch-all for the unchecked exceptions (since all the unchecked exceptions extend from it), much in the same way that the `Exception` class is the catch-all for checked exceptions.

As has been mentioned before, the only real difference is that for checked exceptions you *have* to handle them (by letting them pass or catching them) and the compiler will make sure of it - on the other hand, the handling of unchecked exceptions is optional.

It all boils down to the expected usage of each exception type - you're supposed do be able to recover from checked exceptions (or at least do something about them, when they occur), whilst for unchecked exceptions, there might not be a reasonable way to recover from them. This of course, is a bit subjective.

Comment: Isn't it better to just catch Trowable ?
From  [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html), I can see that every error and exception is a descendand of Throwable.

Comment: @Kinnison84 it's a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable) precisely because of that: you'd end up catching more things than you imagine, and some won't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

They *can* be handled, but you don't *have to*. If you don't handle them, they will propagate and climb up the calling methods stack, until one of them catches it. If none does, the program will crash.

Usually, the bottom line is that if a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, then it should be a **checked exception**. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, then it's ok to have it as an **unchecked exception**.

Also, **checked exceptions** are useful to document an API that you expect to be used by 3rd-parties. When they know your method can throw a specific exception, they will code accordingly and handle the case. If you only use **unchecked exceptions**, all bets are off.

A common pattern (some people don't like it, but in some cases it's ok when you know what you're doing) is to wrap thrown checked exceptions into unchecked ones.

```
try {
   ... code that can throw CheckedException ...
} catch (CheckedException oopsSomethingBadHappened) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Something bad happened!", oopsSomethingBadHappened);
}
```

Comment: I feel that pattern is used for the convenience of the developer but ignoring the extra work that the API users need to do to guess what the developer had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to think about the difference is to think the checking refers to the compile. If an exception is a checked exception, the compiler will check that your code either throws the exception or handles it in a try/catch block at compile-time. For unchecked exceptions, the compiler won't do such a check. You can handle checked/unchecked exceptions the same way (with try/catch/throws), the difference just lies in the checks the compiler performs. This post has a decent [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Guillaume:

- unchecked exceptions are usually programming errors, which should not happen at all if implemented correctly (index out of bound, null pointer, class cast,...) and therefore the caller/ user usually cannot do anything about them.
- checked exceptions are thrown because it was outside of the control of the programmer (network not availabe, filesystem not available, concurrent modifications such as duplicated primary key,...)
- errors are usually thrown by the JVM and the application usually has to stop (out of memory, stack overflow,...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can throw unchecked exceptions with `throw`. And yes, you can catch unchecked exceptions in a `catch` block.

Comment: You can also propagate them with `throws` explicitly, which is optional, but can make things clearer in the method signature.

Comment: @Thilo, Hmmm, throws for unchecked exceptions? I can't think of a case where it would be useful... Usually unchecked exceptions are meant NOT to be caught, because they represent programming errors and your program SHOULD crash in this case. Saying to a client that you expect to throw them would be confusing in my opinion. Which case do you have in mind?

Comment: The Java SDK API is full of `throws IndexOutOfBoundsException` and friends. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and also @Michael's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can handle the unchecked exception but not compulsory. Actually it depends on application developer. Below is the possible reason where i think required to handle even unchecked exception.

- If your application is large where many developers are calling each other API. It is better to handle the unchecked exception otherwise at the end your program will crash which stop the other functionality. So even the simple NullPointerException can stop your program working.
- Imagine you have one scheduler which processing the user data and which is in million size and for the bad data you only want to print the log not to stop working for other good data. In that case if you have not handle the exception one bad data can stop your program

Answer (score -3):

yes we can handle Runtime Exception, plz check below code

```
public class Demo {
  static void m1() {
    int a[]=new int [5];
    try {
    a[12]=2;
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    m1();
   try {
    String s=null;

    System.out.println(s.length());
   }catch(Exception e) {

   }
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```