# using keyword throws to declare throwing of Runtime Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

For me, these code

```
static int faktorial (int n) throws ArithmeticException {
  if ((n < 0) || (n > 31)) { 
    throw new ArithmeticException();
  } 
  if (n > 1) {
    return n * faktorial(n - 1);
  } 
  else {
    return 1;
  }    
}
```

and the same code without

```
throws ArithmeticException
```

do the same, when I use it with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    int n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  

    System.out.print("Insert integer number: ");        
    n = sc.nextInt();         
    System.out.println(n + "! = " + faktorial(n));
  }
  catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Not an integer number!");
    e. printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println("Number is too big!");
    e. printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Could someone describe me if use of

```
    throws ArithmeticException
```

has some advantages in my code.

I will also appreciate some good example of using keyword `throws`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is an [unchecked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104407/cant-java-unchecked-exceptions-be-handled-using-try-catch-block), listing it in the `throws` specification has no effect as far as the compiler is concerned.

Nonetheless, I think it is a good idea to keep the `throws` specification for documentation purposes.

That said, `ArithmeticException` is probably not the right exception to be throwing when the function is called with an invalid argument. Using [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) would be more appropriate.

Comment: it has its upsides, so you can't just say it's redundant

Comment: @Keppil It does **not** force you to catch it.

Comment: @NPE I added what I find an another upside of it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745183/575659

Answer (score 3):

The above method signature uses the the expression `throws ArithmeticException` to tell
the user of this function that method could throw this exception and they should be 
aware and catch it (if they want - "want" only because this exception is unchecked - and plan a workaround in that case).

Except that ArithmeticException is not the proper exception to use in this case (you could technically use any one of them). A better exception to throw would be `IllegalArgumentException` since it implies the argument that was passed in was improper.

Answer (score 3):

Aside of what's beeing said, there is one upside that I find helping me code.

Eclipse can use that information (that the method is declared with `throws RuntimeException`) and (on demand) add **proper** catch clause.

Lets look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
}

private static void test() {
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}

public static void foo() {

}

public static void bar() throws NullPointerException {

}

public static void baz() throws IllegalArgumentException {

}
```

adding `try/ catch block` inside method `test` will result in:

```
private static void test() {
    try {
        foo();
        bar();
        baz();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That's nice, isn't it? However, it works only with 1st level method invocation, so it does not pollute higher levels of abstraction with multiple catches of runtime exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void test() {
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

That's nice as well.

Anyway, seeing that throws in javadoc is probably much more important :)

```
void Test.baz() throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java does not provide a simple True/False flag to determine whether a given exception is [checked or unchecked](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129), you need to be aware of what types of exceptions you (as programmer) has to deal with (either catch or re-throw) and which you can chose not to handle (effectively ignore).

In particular, the entire `RunTimeException` class is unchecked, and `ArithmeticException` is its sub-class.