# Scala - Breaking out of a loop in a try-catch block

Tags: scala, try-catch, break

I have the following Scala code:

```
breakable {
  someFile.foreach { anotherFile =>
    anotherFile.foreach { file =>
      try {
        val booleanVal = getBoolean(file)
        if (booleanVal) break //break out of the try/catch + both loops
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it's the `if (booleanVal) break` that doesn't work, because it seems like Scala makes it work as an exception. How do I break out of this nested loop?

Comment: Any issue in  calling return?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do this. Some more context (like types) might help someone find that way.

Comment: and maybe you should also take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `if (booleanVal) break` out of try block:

```
val booleanVal = try { 
  getBoolean(file)
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => //do something
}
if (booleanVal) break // break out of the try/catch + both loops
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use break, for the first this is ugly :) and the second, this is unreadable.
Maybe you would like something like this:

```
for {
  anotherFile <- someFile
  file <- anotherFile
  b <- Try(getBoolean(file))
  if(b)
} /// do something
```

If you need to do more work in the try block, you can write:

```
for {
    anotherFile <- someFile
    file <- anotherFile
} Try{ if(!getBoolean(file)) /* */ } match {
  case onSuccess(v) =>
  case onFailure(e: Throwable) =>
}
```