# Is memory out of bound exception or error?

Tags: java, memory, deployment, server, out-of-memory

Is memory out of bound exception or error? We usually get this during project deployment on the server. It might be a basic question. I googled it but I could not find relevant answer so posting here.

*Error I got:*

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray` - Object size: 8216, Num elements: 2049

And how can we handle this?

Comment: Could you post the full error message? Its quite hard to guess what you mean from the little info you provide.

Comment: check this and you will see what it extends https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Comment: Basically catching Exception you will miss!

Comment: @PetterFriberg Now I get what he wants.

Comment: Please be a lot more specific than you have so far, OP. Everyone seems to be trying to guess what you mean.

Comment: @AndrewRegan, was trying to find a duplicate before answering.

Comment: You're probably right, Petter, but question definitely needs an edit.

Comment: IndexOfOutBoundException is a RuntimeException and OutOfMemoryError is an Error.  You need to know what the actual name of the error is.

Comment: Thanks All. Here it is the error:  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray - Object size: 8216, Num elements: 2049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) extends `java.lang.Error` and **not**  `java.lang.Exception`

catching `Exception` you will miss it

```
try{
....
}catch(Exception ex){
 //will not catch OutOfMemoryError, since it does not extend Exception
}
```

catching `Throwable`, you will hit'em both..

```
try{
....
}catch(Throwable ex){
 //will catch both Exception and OutOfMemoryError, they both extend this
}
```

Whether it is good or not to catch `Throwable` is another question see this [Is it a bad practice to catch Throwable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable) (Thanks to @Dawnkeeper for link)

Comment: just adding that catching Throwables might not really help you as Errors tend to not be recoverable. see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable)