# What is the difference between handling exceptions by catch block directly parent class and subclasses

Tags: java, exception

I have the following Java code

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public void testException(){
    try{
        Assert.assertEquals(1,2);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the test is run, the assertion fails and exception is printed as standard output and the TestNG shows the test result as FAILED.

If I catch the same exception using

```
catch(AssertionError e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the exception is printed as error output and the TestNG shows the test result as PASSED. In both cases exception is handled, but what is the difference here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AssertionError` is not a sub-class of `Exception` (it's a sub-class of `Error`), so the first snippet, with the `catch(Exception e)` handler, doesn't catch it. Therefore the test result is FAILED.

The second snippet catches the exception, so as far a `TestNG` is concerned, no exceptions occurred in the test of `testException()` and the result is PASSED.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) is child of `Throwable` and `Error`, not from `Exception`:

```
java.lang.Object
   java.lang.Throwable
       java.lang.Error
           java.lang.AssertionError
```

So the line:

```
catch(Exception e){
```

Won't catch it in the case of error. What you can do is:

```
catch(Error e){
```

or

```
catch(Throwable t){
```

But you must be careful as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083271/3850595)