# What is the meaning of this statement from a blog saying a function has to declare Throwable at method signature to catch it?

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I am trying to understand exception handling in Java and i keep running into variations of the below mentioned confusing statement in several articles -

> There are several reasons why catching instance of java.lang.Throwable is bad idea, because **in order to catch them you have to declare at your method signature e.g. public void doSomething() throws Throwable**.

This is from http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/why-catching-throwable-or-error-is-bad.html#ixzz4hQPkFktf

However, this code compiles -

```
class CatchThrowable
{

    void function()
    {

        try
        {
            throw new Throwable();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try
        {

        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Both main and function are able to catch Throwable without declaring that they throw it. My understanding is that the *throws* keyword is used to declare the checked exceptions which a function throws, not those which it catches. Please clarify the quoted statement.

Comment: If you catch it in the method, then the method doesn't throw it *outside*. Capiche?

Comment: yes, i think the tutorial meant the method that will throw the exception should have `throws Exception` in it's signature

Comment: I don't think the blog makes this very clear.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-throwable

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

> **order to catch them you have to declare at your method signature e.g. public void doSomething() throws Throwable**.

is basically wrong.

You just have to understand the following. There is a exception Hierarchy
[image]
A method can throw all types of exception, it just depends on your needs which one you catch and which one not.

It is also not a good idea to catch `Error` (which includes that you should also not catch `Throwable`) because there are some severe JMV-`VirtualMachineError`'s like `OutOfMemoryError` which you usually not should catch.

But this has nothing to do which the fact, what a method declares in its `throws` part.